# Jquery change background colour for a selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code div in 4*4 format :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function(e){

    var id_val=this.id;

    var word = id_val.split("-").pop();
    alert(word)
    e.preventDefault();

    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
    if(i!=word)
    {
     $("#div-"+i+"").css("background-color","white");
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">
     <p>div1</p>
        <div id="div-2">
  <p>div2</p>
            <div id="div-3">
   <p>div3</p>
    <div id="div-4">
     <p>div4</p>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have written the jquery code when on click the particular div has to change colour to red and remaining div colour should be white

When I have executed this only the div1 has changing the colour to red and other divs are not changing the colour.

for eg :

if I click div1 change to red colour and other div2,div3,div4 should be in white 
color
If I click div2 change to red colour and other div1,div3,div4 should be in white

### color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent the other div elements from triggering as well.

you didn't properly terminate the first two lines with `});` at the end of the script.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function(e) {

      var id_val = this.id;

      var word = id_val.split("-").pop();
      if (word != null) {
      alert(word)
      e.stopPropagation();

      for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (parseInt(i) === parseInt(word)) {
          $("#div-" + i + "").css("background-color", "red");
      
        } else {
            $("#div-" + i + "").css("background-color", "white");
        }
      }
     }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">
  <p>div1</p>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>div2</p>
    <div id="div-3">
      <p>div3</p>
      <div id="div-4">
        <p>div4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with this for the user click on particular div it is not changing the colour..

Comment: @Mahesh I updated the answer -- seems to work properly now

Comment: Thanks..! it works for me..please let me know what is the use of : e.stopPropagation();..??

Comment: @Mahesh event.stopPropogation() stops the event from bubbling (firing multiple times due to an object having multiple parents with similar  bound events). Example:  you have three divs, all nested inside of each other,  if you do $("div").click()  and click in the third div (nested inside the other two), it will trigger the event 3 times, one for each div that you clicked in.  event.stopPropogration() will cause it to only fire once and stop before firing for each parent div. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this simple code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div").click(function(e) {
  $('div[id^="div-"] p').css("background-color", "white"); //change the remaining elements who's id start with div- color to white 
  if ($(e.target).is('p')) {
    $(e.target).css("background-color", "red"); //change the clicked element color
  }
});

});
```

```js
$("div").click(function(e) {
  $('div[id^="div-"] p').css("background-color", "white"); //change the remaining elements who's id start with div- color to white 
  if ($(e.target).is('p')) {
    $(e.target).css("background-color", "red"); //change the clicked element color
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">
  <p>div1</p>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>div2</p>
    <div id="div-3">
      <p>div3</p>
      <div id="div-4">
        <p>div4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I do the second click on the div2, its not changing color to red..please check or share my jsfiddle link..pls

Comment: why do i want to share your jsfiddle, and why, why do you have your divs inside other divs?

Comment: Click between div1 and div 2 :) I prefer to use 'p' instead of 'div'.

Comment: This answer seems to trigger on other divs outside of the 4 elements that the question probably was referring to

Comment: @Mahesh  e.stopPropagation() stops the bubbling of the click event

Answer (score 0):

Try something Like that

```
$("div").click(function(e){
$("div[id^='div-']").css("background-color","white");
$(this).css("background-color","red");
}
```

Comment: HI,only for the first click the div1 is changed colour to red and other divs are white, when I do second clicked on the div2 it is not changing colour to red and other divs are not changing color to white

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e.stopPropagation()` and not `e.preventDefault()`. Also since divs are nested you should give a color to the inside `p` tag and not the `div` itself. Also terminate your function correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div").click(function(e){

var id_val=this.id;
$(this).first("p").css("background-color","red")
var word = id_val.split("-").pop();
alert(word)
e.stopPropagation();

for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
if(i!=word)
{
 $("#div-"+i+"").css("background-color","white");
}
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">
    <p>div1</p>
    <div id="div-2">
    <p>div2</p>
        <div id="div-3">
        <p>div3</p>
            <div id="div-4">
                <p>div4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mahesh can you check this answer and let me know if it works for u

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
        $("div").click(function (e) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            $('div:not(#' + this.id + ')').css("background-color", "white");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
```

Comment: Can u please let me know what is the use of e.stopImmediatePropagation();??

Comment: e.stopPropagation() will stop only parent events from running while e.stopImmediatePropagation() will stop all events from running. In this scenario you could get away with just using e.stopPropagation() to be honest.